# How can i implement the "last seen" function for webshops

Tags: html, css, webshop

Im wondering how i can display a row on my homepage with a row (collection) that displays all the last products visitor clicked. If anybody got any tips or could guide me in the right direction it be great !

thanks

Comment: Omnomnom! Coockies?

Answer (score 1):

Use local or session storage and on each product clicked - on clicking a product use setItem() to add it to the list stored in LS and then use getItem() to display all previously viewed items.

You can search for appropriate code to use for setting and getting items in local / session storage. If you only want the items that the user views in the session - then use session stoage, and if you want to store items that they have viewed over multiple sessions then use local storage. Same syntax for setting and getting but use the different names. The difference is that local storage has persistence over multiople page views / sessions whereas session storage only lasts for that given session.

Three things - local and session storage are not secure so do NOT store sensitive information like passwords. and secondly - LS / SS store items as a string so you will need to deal with that when you get items out of it or add items to it and third - not all browsers will be configured to use LS / SS (eg if a user is in incognito mode) - so you may need to do a check to see if they an use webstorage and provide an alternative if not.